# Fraction problem

Tags: arithmetic, fractions

I have been reading *Basic Math and Pre Algebra for Dummies*, the question below has me stumped!

> David bought a cake for himself and his friends. He cut a piece for himself that was $1/6$ of the total cake. The Sharon cut a piece that was $1/5$ of what was left. Then Armand cut a piece that was $1/2$ of what was left. How much of the cake was left after all three friends had taken their pieces?

The answer in the book is $1/3$, is this a mistake ?

When he ate $1/6$ there was $5/6$ left, so  $5/6 - 1/5  = 19/30$ 
$19/30  - 1/2$?   am I on the wrong path here?

Comment: i can not see any problem here

Comment: Did you get a different value?  If so, edit your post to show the calculation you did.

Comment: Ah, Sharon didn't take $\frac 15$ of the original...she ate $\frac 15$ of what was left after David ate his bit.  Thus Sharon took $\frac 15$ of $\frac 56$, so Sharon took $\frac 16$ of the original...same as David.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing is to keep track of how much of the cake is left after each operation, not how much is consumed. To find the remaining part, one subtracts the eaten part from $1$ and multiplies out, so you get
$$
\left(1 - \frac{1}{6}\right) \times \left(1 - \frac{1}{5}\right)
                             \times \left(1 - \frac{1}{2}\right)
= \frac{5}{6} \times \frac{4}{5} \times \frac{1}{2}
= \frac{1}{3}
$$

Comment: what I don't understand is why I cant just subtract  ,  5/6 - 1/5  = 19 /30 - 1/2 ?

Comment: @paul because then you have the 2nd guy eat $1/5$ of the original cake, not of what was left

Comment: hey tx for your help !    I had an aha moment! after reading and testing your last comment.  cheers!

Answer (score 2):

$\frac{1}{6}$ is taken off the bat, so we're left with $\frac{5}{6}$ of a cake. Then $\frac{1}{5}$ of that is taken, so $\frac{1}{5}\times\frac{5}{6}=\frac{1}{6}$ of the original cake is taken. Now we have $1-2\times\frac{1}{6}=\frac{2}{3}$ of the original cake left. Finally, half of the remaining cake is taken, so $\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{2}{3}=\frac{1}{3}$ of the original cake is taken. Thus, we are left with $\frac{2}{3}-\frac{1}{3}=\frac{1}{3}$ of the original cake left.

Comment: I think I am looking at these questions wrong  , I took the root of  5/6 - 1/5  = 19/30

Comment: @paul The trick is that it's $1/5$ of the remaining cake is taken, so you have to scale the amount of remaining cake by $1/5$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the answer given in the book is correct, you just have to add up all the fractions in the following way;
$$
\frac{1}{6}+\frac{5}{6}\cdot \frac{1}{5}+\frac{5}{6}\cdot \frac{4}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}=1
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint. I put the words into this equation
$$\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{5}\left(1-\frac{1}{6}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{5}\left(1-\frac{1}{6}\right)\right)+x=1.$$
What is the value of $x$?